# Blazor routing with regex

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-routing

I am new to Blazor and looking what are the possibilities with this.
I would like to migrate my asp.net website to blazor.
I actually have urls like this :

```
www.mywebsite.fr/product/a-12
www.mywebsite.fr/product/details/a-12
www.mywebsite.fr/toto/tata/titi/b-9
```

But in the following documentation url, it seems that Blazor doesn't manage urls with regex.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I tried the following directive :

```
@page "/product/{Id:regex(^a\-\d{1,2}$)}"
```

but without success :(

Am I wrong ?
If not, how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all routes and handle it at component level:

```cs
@page "/product/{*pageRoute}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? PageRoute { get; set; }
}
```

After having `PageRoute` you can then decide, based on regex, to navigate user away, or process with request. In case above, if your route be `product/123/456/a-2`, `PageRoute` paramater will be `123/456/a-2`.

Comment: Yes, it's a possibility, although it's not ideal.

Comment: As you mentioned, it's not yet possible with existing router. You can either create your own router, or use workaround.